# Looking for a restaurant in Vienna with a name similar to "An die 2 Linsen" that served huge Schnitzel

Tags: restaurants, vienna

In 2012 during an Euro-trip I spent some days in Vienna. During that trip I got a recommendation for a restaurant from a local citizen. I really liked the restaurant and memorized it's name for future usage.

Fast forward to December 2019, I have a couple of friends in Vienna and I suggested this same restaurant to them, but to my disappointment I can't find anything about it! Probably my memory is playing me a trick, but I have a few things about this restaurant that I know for sure:

1. It's name is something that sounds like "*An die 2 Linsen*", or *Lieser*, or something that sounds alike
2. It served huge-sized *Schnitzel*. I said HUGE.
3. It was open in February 2012, probably longer.
4. It was within walking distance from Vienna's historic center (*St Peter's church*), even though a little longer than usual. I'd say half an hour walking.

   Does anyone know the name of this specific restaurant and if it's still open as of December 2019?

Comment: There are others, if you are interested. Figlmüller is known for its big Schnitzel.

Comment: When you said "HUGE" I was expecting, say, the size of a plaice or something. The ones pictured [here](http://www.2lieserln.at/speisekarte_e.html) look like... normal schnitzel?

Comment: @AakashM Photos on [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.de/Restaurant_Review-g190454-d941719-Reviews-Zu_den_2_Lieserln-Vienna.html) are more like I remember them!

Comment: FWIW, the (very few) times I had schnitzels in Poland and Czech Republic, they were that big. So there´s a good chance you'll find them again. Good luck!

Comment: You might want to keep in mind that just because a Wienerschnitzel has a large area does not mean you actually get a lot of it. One part of the preparation process is to beat the veal with a mallet to flatten it. The more you flatten it, the more impressive it looks on the plate, but the guest acutally just gets more (cheap) breadcrumbs around the same amount of (expensive) veal.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A quick search led me to this (German) [article](https://www.vienna.at/wiener-traditions-beisl-zu-den-2-lieserln-hat-zugesperrt/3266791), which states:

> Das bei Touristen und Wienern gleichermaßen beliebte Traditions-Beisl "Zu den 2 Lieserln" hat zugesperrt. Auf der Homepage bedankt sich der Inhaber für die Treue und gibt bekannt, dass man "den Kampf gegen die äußeren Umstände verloren" habe und das "geliebte Gasthaus für immer schließen" müsse.

Roughly translated, the restaurant "Zu den 2 Lieserln" has been closed (for ever).
This article is dated May 2012, which leaves room for your visit earlier that year.

Their [website](http://www.2lieserln.at/start_e.html) is still online, but [tripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.de/Restaurant_Review-g190454-d941719-Reviews-Zu_den_2_Lieserln-Vienna.html) also states it as "Geschlossen", German for closed.

So I fear you'll have to find a different place to go this December!

Comment: Danke! That's the one! Too bad it's not open anymore... I'd never find it, since _Lieserln_ is not a german word! r is it? Perhaps a question for [German.SE](https://german.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @gmauch *Lieserln* sounds like two women named Elisabeth.

Comment: indeed. Elisabeth and Lieselotte, former owners.

Comment: @gmauch German has many different diminutive forms in different regions.  *Lieserl* is a diminutive female name (traditionally a nickname), similar to *Liesl;* the plural is formed by adding *n,* yielding *Lieserln.*  The *-erl* suffix may also be seen in Mozart's sister's nickname, *Nannerl.*  Her given names were *Maria Anna.*

Comment: @phoog Thanks for the explanation! I only knew the _chen_ diminutive. Besides that, [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=lb&tl=en&text=Lieserln) told me that _Lieserln_ is Luxembourgish for _readers_ and I was conjecturing that the owners were two avid readers.

Comment: @gmauch machine translation is often amusing.  Wikipedia's [list of diminutives by language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diminutives_by_language) has an overview of German diminutives.  Standard High German also uses *-lein* in addition to *-chen.*  I'm sure I've seen a map of favored suffixes in different regions, but I can't find one now on the web.

Comment: @phoog I would really like to see such a map, if you ever find it!

Answer (score 11):

Since there is no shortage of Wiener Schnitzel tourist traps this insider [Schnitzel guide](https://www.vienna-unwrapped.com/wienerschnitzel-vienna/) may help. I have also been recently at restaurant 'Zum Friedensrichter' in Leopoldstadt - not huge Schnitzel but VERY good ones!