# Identify schnitzel restaurant in Kitzingen, Germany

Tags: germany, identify-this, restaurants

When I was stationed in Wuerzburg, Germany (from 1989 to 1993) on active duty in the US Army, there was a restaurant in Kitzingen, the next city over, that my fellow Soldiers called "The Schnitzel Factory" because the schnitzels they served were, in a word, huge.

Anyone have an idea what this restaurant is/was called, and whether or not it's still there?

Comment: It might be Gasthaus Zum Einhorn or Gasthaus Zum Kitzengen.

Comment: What is this, an [international huge schnitzel day](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/150438/looking-for-a-restaurant-in-vienna-with-a-name-similar-to-an-die-2-linsen-that)?

Answer (score 9):

According to a comment on [yelp.de](https://www.yelp.de/biz/wirtshaus-zum-m%C3%BChlberg-kitzingen), the restaurant Zum Mühlberg (Wörthstr. 46, 97318 Kitzingen) is also called Schnitzelfabrik:

> Die Schnitzelfabrik wird das Gasthaus auch genannt die waren früher schon in Reperndorf erste Sahne Riesen Portionen und auch günstig. Kein Nobelschuppen sondern ne schöne kleine Kneipe mit Biergarten.

Translation:

> The inn is also called schnitzel factory, it was formerly in Reperndorf. Top quality, giant portions and also cheap. No fancy location but a nice little pub with beer garden.

Edit: I haven't found a telephone number or web site. According to yelp, they have closed.

Comment: I was married to a serviceman and lived in Poppenweiler in 1972 - 1973. We went to the schnitzel factory quite a few times. The schnitzels were huge and very, very good!